# android xml layout 7' and 10'

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed Relative layout for 3.7 droids with Relative layout and difficult relations of layout elements... imageViews and buttons of different sizes...  I want to make xml layouts for 7' and 10' droids... I know how to do it by hands... But... Is there any way, (maybe) program which can do it automatically (generate xml for 7 or 10')???

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_previous9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Button_next_9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fwd" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagepygalo9"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cvety9skr"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/s221" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cvety91"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:clickable="false"
       android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/sl4101" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cvety92"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:clickable="false"
       android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/sl4102" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cvety93"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:clickable="false"
       android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/sl4102" />
```

example...
Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think. I spent much time to create layout on android by and. you could try if this layout goes well on tablet ( 7' and 10') and if it doesn't fit well you could create the same layout in a different folder (layout-xlarge) and apply the changes to fit that layout onto tablet

Comment: So I do... large, small, xlarge.... but as I understand - you need to increase the meanings of "...dp" according to every size... Am I wrong?

Comment: no, dp means density-independent pixels, so dp takes different dimension to every screen size. so you have to try this layout on tablet and apply changes to it modifying the dimension or other that is different from other layout